# mariadb 10.1.13 galera cluster : error

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, mariadb, galera

mariadb 10.1.x galera cluster setting.

first node 192.168.159.132

## /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.159.132,192.168.159.135,192.168.159.136
binlog_format=row
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
```

first node 192.168.159.132

## $ sudo service mysql bootstrap

```
* Bootstrapping the cluster mysqld
Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

## $ systemctl status mariadb.service

```
[ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
[ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1379: Failed to open channel 'my_wsrep_cluster' at 'gcomm://192.168.32.251,192.168.32.252,192.168.32...ection timed out)
[ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
[ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.32.251,192.168.32.252,192.168.32.253) failed: 7
[ERROR] Aborting
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

## Why "Galera Cluster" not Start?

## How To checking "Connection Time Out"?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Error in your config. After **gcom** you only use one **:** like:

```
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.159.132,192.168.159.135,192.168.159.136
```

Comment: See above : Error "Connection Time Out"

Answer (score 1):

their is an error:

use format as  below:

```
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://first_ip,second_ip,third_ip"
```

Answer (score 1):

The galera configuration looks fine. But you have to provide an extra argument while bootstrapping the first node. Try this:

```
mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster
```

For the first node `wsrep_cluster_address` can be empty. For next nodes you have to provide at least one ip address that is already a part of cluster. But it's a good practice to provide the list of all the nodes that you are going to use. It wont give you any error for mentioning a node in cluster-address which is not present in the cluster yet. So you can use, `wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.159.132,192.168.159.135,192.168.159.136` for every node.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "connection timed out" because the node is trying to connect to the other nodes listed in wsrep_cluster_address, which aren't online as this is the very first node in the cluster. So, during bootstrap you should start the first node with empty wsrep_cluster_address :.**wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://'**.